# how to set up a fixed position image in a one page layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I am doing a single page design using a fullpage.js component. the code is something like so..

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section1">Some section</div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">Some section</div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">Some section</div>
    <div class="section" id="section4">Some section</div>
</div>
```

I would like to set up a fixed image - which is the title logo from section 2 onwards.

Section1 will be a photo background - but page 2/3/4 - I want to have an a title div/image to be fixed as the pages/section scroll.

Is that possible ?

codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXMgmV

thanks

Comment: Check [the example available in fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/fixedHeaders.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a single line of `css`

```
.fp-viewing-0 .title.fixed{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

You can animate it if you want using [css-animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) to have `transition` or `delay`

See the **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/XKXERZ)**

Comment: this works great... a question - is there any way to animate the appearance to be more graceful ? like opacity wise etc ?

Comment: @hypermails Yes. I will update the codepen and get back to you.

Comment: As I know, there is a callback function named onLeave in fullpage.js. You can use it. When you leave first section, you can add simply fadeIn or slideDown jquery effects for your hidden image, when you return page one, you can hide your image. [Callback functions for fullpage.js][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks